# String multiplication: taking too much time

Tags: string, c++14

I am trying to make an efficient program for multiplying big numbers and came up with the following solution :-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string Addem(string a,string b)  // To add two large numbers,only for +ve numbers
{
    string c;
    int n=a.size(),m=b.size();
    if(m>n)
    {
        swap(n,m);
        swap(a,b);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<n-m; i++)  // adding zeros to make lengths of both string equal.
    b='0'+b;
    int carry=0,curr=0;
    for(int i=n-1; i>-1; i--)
    {
      curr=a[i]-'0'+b[i]-'0'+carry;   //basic school math to find sum, using  
      carry=curr/10;                 //two variables to find sum of each place individually
      curr=curr%10;                 //and passing carry to the next position.
      c=(char)(curr+'0')+c;
      if(i==0 && carry)
      {
        c=(char)(carry+'0')+c;
      }
    }
    while(c[0]=='0' && c.size()!=1)       //removing any leading zeros
        c.erase(0,1);
 return c;
}

string Multiplyem(string a,string b) // To multiply two large numbers.
{
    bool sign=1;
    if( (a[0]=='-' && b[0]=='-') || (a[0]!='-' && b[0]!='-') )
        sign=0;
    if(a[0]=='-')
        a.erase(0,1);         //taking care of sign.
    if(b[0]=='-')
        b.erase(0,1);
    if(a=="0" || b=="0")
        return "0";
    string c;
    int curr=0,carry=0;
    int n=a.size(),m=b.size();
    for(int i=m-1; i>-1; i--)
    {
      string tmp;                        //string to store result of a*(current digit of b)
      for(int j=n-1; j>-1; j--)
       {
         curr=carry+(b[i]-'0')*(a[j]-'0');    //scroll down for this,explained 
         carry=curr/10;                      //the logic for this under EDIT        
         curr=curr%10;
         tmp=(char)(curr+'0')+tmp;
         if(j==0 && carry)
         {
             tmp=(char)(carry+'0')+tmp;
         }
       }
       for(int j=m-1; j>i; j--)   //adding zeros take care of number positions
        tmp+='0';
       c=Addem(tmp,c);              //adding tmp to c
       carry=0,curr=0;
    }
    while(c[0]=='0' && c.size()!=1)     // removing any leading zeros (if any)
        c.erase(0,1);
    if(sign==1 && c!="0")     //adding sign (if reqired)
        c='-'+c;
  return c;
}
int main()
{
   string a,b;
   cin>>a>>b;
   cout<<"Multiplication = "<<Multiplyem(a,b)<<" \n \n";
}
```

as far as i can see the complexity is O(m*n) but, when i actually try it out, it takes too much time.
I have tried out the same test case on another code with seemingly the same complexity but, that one executes it in 0.04 sec. whereas mine takes 1.02 sec.

[GFG solution](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/6JeojamLwf) (takes 0.04 sec)

[My solution](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/ubrQ46QV6m) (takes about a whole second)

Any help on this is appreciated.

EDIT: I have added some comments if that would help, basically what i am doing is taking last digit of one number and multiplying it with the other number ( i.e 
 tmp = b[m-1] * a ) and storing it in a string (say c), repeating this with the second last digit ( tmp = b[m-2] * a ), adding a zero at the end of the string (to take care of ten's place) and adding this to the string c using the function `Addem` defined above ( basically c = c + tmp*10 ), repeating the process until we run out of digits while increasing the number of zero to be added at the end of the string. This should take O(m*n).

I kind of suspect this is due to using + operator or std::erase as std::erase takes O(n) time, but i am not quite sure.

Comment: An explaination about the algorithm you came up with would be appreciated. Try to give it in the form of steps and then describe how you implemented each step. This way, it is quickier for us to understand where your algorithm fails

Comment: added some comments and an explanation for my logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your solution, you are computing the temp string for each digit multiplication and adding it up incrementally to the final string.
Skip that and switch to a common mutable structure(like the result vector in CFG solution) and keep updating only that structure at the correct places.

As numbers grow, temp will be like

```
e.g. 100000*29990
    0
   90
  900
 9000
20000
```

With every temp + c operation, there are going to be a lot of zeroes in the end. For all those, you are still doing operations like 0+0 or 0+(non-zero number) which are unnecessary.